# Removing custom objects from arraylist and returning the clean arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't seem to understand how I can remove duplicate objects out of a arrayList.
I have the folowing method, but it doesn't work.

```java
    private ArrayList<Road> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Road> array, int useless) {
        ArrayList<Road> arrayFixed = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Road road : array) {
            if (!arrayFixed.contains(road)) {
                System.out.println("Im adding this road");
                System.out.println("Road X: " + road.getX());
                System.out.println("Road Y: " + road.getY());
                arrayFixed.add(road);
            }
        }

        return arrayFixed;
    }
```

I have an ArrayList with roads (Object) that can have duplicates and I want the method to return an ArrayList without those duplicates.

**This is the road class**

```java
public class Road {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private String imgPath;
    private String color;
```

Comment: How dows your `Road` object look like?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I added it

Comment: Use your IDE to generate equals and hashcode for `Road`.

Comment: By the way, to automatically eliminate duplicate objects, use a `Set` rather than a `List`. To keep the objects in order, use a `SortedSet` or a `NavigableSet` such as `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is not the `removeDuplicates` method. Instead is probably the equals method in the Road class. `List.contains(...)` uses this equals method to compare if the list contains the given element. So to make your code work as expected you should override the equals method in the Road class to perform the needed comparison.
Depending on the Road class implementation this could look like this for example:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Road road = (Road) o;
    return Objects.equals(road.x, x) &&
            Objects.equals(road.y, y) &&
            Objects.equals(imgPath, road.imgPath) &&
            Objects.equals(color, road.color);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(x, y, imgPath, color);
}
```

As already pointed out in the comments these methods are usually generated using your IDE and only adjusted when needed. When adjusting them you have to take into consideration that there is a contract (which can be found in the docs) between equals and hashcode which has to be considered for various reasons (for example using hashsets).

Comment: So the 2 if statements are standard and the last lines are what I should change?
Because then I can implement it in another class.

Comment: Never implement `equals()` without `hashCode()`

Comment: Totally right, I will add it to the answer @MuratKaragöz

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have overridden `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the class, `Road` something like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    Road other = (Road) obj;
    return Objects.equals(imgPath, other.imgPath) && Objects.equals(color, other.color)
            && Objects.equals(x, other.x) && Objects.equals(y, other.y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(imgPath, color, x, y);
}
```

Also, instead of writing so many lines in your method, you can write just one line using Stream API as follows:

```
private List<Road> removeDuplicates(List<Road> array) {
    return array.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```